# Amazon SDK in Yii framework

Tags: amazon-web-services, yii, namespaces

Trying to get the new Amazon SDK
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/guide/latest/quick-start.html
in Yii Framework.

Amazon doc says to use like this:

```
// Include the SDK using the Composer autoloader
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Aws\S3\S3Client;

// Instantiate the S3 client with your AWS credentials
$s3Client = S3Client::factory(array(
    'key'    => 'YOUR_AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID',
    'secret' => 'YOUR_AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY',
));
```

But you can not use "use" in a method of a controller in Yii, so in Yii you can use setPathOfAlias to use namespaces.

I'm trying with this:

```
            Yii::import('application.vendors.amazon-sdk.*');
            Yii::setPathOfAlias('AwsSDK',Yii::getPathOfAlias('application.vendors.amazon-sdk.*'));
            require 'aws-autoloader.php';

            // Instantiate the S3 client with your AWS credentials
            $aws = AwsSDK\Aws\Common\Aws::factory(array(
                'key'    => '************',
                'secret' => '************',
            ));
```

It's loading the "Aws.php" correctly, but it says "Fatal error: Class 'AwsSDK\Aws\Common\Aws' not found"

What is the problem ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Is this for Yii 1.*?

In that case, just check how I configured it:
https://github.com/IvoRe/ES32

"*But you can not use "use" in a method of a controller in Yii*"

Aren't you supposed to use "use" at the top of a class? So the use declaration would come before the Controller declaration.

Quote from [this tutorial](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/namespacing-in-php-2/):

> Aliasing or importing should occur in the highest scope of a namespace
>   or in the global scope. Trying to do this in the scope of a method or
>   function is invalid syntax.

Comment: I don't want to put the "use" at the beginning of the file, I need to put in the method.

Comment: I do not believe that this is possible. `Use` must always appear before a class definition. It is an instruction to the parser.